# in React i need to get the state from local storage and then set another state conditionally based on this state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, state

```
const  [isDone, setIsDone] = useState({
      customer: undefined, //need to set another state based on this state
      shipping: undefined,
      payment: undefined,
    });

    //Set values of isdone on page load from localstorage if exists else set to false
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsDone({
      customer: localStorage.getItem("customer")
      ? localStorage.getItem("customer")
      : false,
      shipping: localStorage.getItem("shipping")
      ? localStorage.getItem("shipping")
      : false,
      payment: localStorage.getItem("payment")
        ? localStorage.getItem("payment")
        : false,
    });

  //if customer section has not been done,set edit clicked to false
    !isDone.customer && setEditClicked({ ...editClicked, customer: true }); //This code block is 
    getting executed evey time,even though state of isDone.customer is set to "true".i confirmed from 
    react dev tools 
     //
      
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

Thing is  IsDone.customer is saved to "true" in local storage, but still this code is not working.i even coverted it to boolen using Boolean method but still same result.

here is how i save data to localstorage.it is working, i have checked it.

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
const name = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("name");

//save isDone to local storage
localStorage.setItem(name, true);
setEditClicked({ ...editClicked, [name]: false });
 };
```

Comment: How do you set the data to localStorage? Is it really saved there? If yes, how is it structured?

Comment: i have edited my question to show the saving into local storage. it is working.i have checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isDone` state won't be changed immediately after `setIsDone` in `useEffect`

It would be better to create another constant inside `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    const isDone = {
      customer: localStorage.getItem("customer")
      ? localStorage.getItem("customer")
      : false,
      shipping: localStorage.getItem("shipping")
      ? localStorage.getItem("shipping")
      : false,
      payment: localStorage.getItem("payment")
        ? localStorage.getItem("payment")
        : false,
    }

    setIsDone(isDone);

    !isDone.customer && setEditClicked({ ...editClicked, customer: true });

  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://prntscr.com/106dqqr

`localStorage` is working with string, So, you need use `JOSN.parse`, and `JSON.stringfy`

```
JSON.stringify(false)
"false"
JSON.parse("false")
false
```

```
var c = localStorage.getItem("customer")
var s = localStorage.getItem("shipping")
var p = localStorage.getItem("payment")

...
 setIsDone({
      customer: c
      ? JSON.parse(c)
      : false,
      shipping: s
      ? JSON.parse(s)
      : false,
      payment: p
        ? JSON.parse(p)
        : false,
    });

...
//save isDone to local storage
localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringfy(true));
```

Comment: but i am already saving strings. name is string variable.it contains string. key value pair is string

Comment: ok i will try this and give you feedback thanks

Comment: nope still not working i think localstorage is not loading immediately as another answer suggests